# Why in this situation only one constructor is called but two destructors are called?

Tags: c++

In the first time,the code looks like below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
    explicit Test(int);
    ~Test();
    //Test(Test&);
    int varInt;
};
Test::Test(int temp){
    varInt = temp;
    cout << "call Test::constructor\n";
}
Test::~Test(){
    cout << "call Test::destructor\n";
}
/*Test::Test(Test&temp){
    varInt = temp.varInt;
    cout << "call Test::copy constructor\n";
}*/
void func(Test temp){
    cout << "call func\n";
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    func(Test(1));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
call Test::constructor
call func
call Test::destructor
call Test::destructor
```

This confuses me,cause there's only one object that was created(as the argument of func),but two destructors were called after the function ends.
I started to wonder,is this because the default copy constructor was called?So I wrote the definition of copy constructor,which made things just more strange.
After I add the Commented-Out Code as you can see above,namely the definition of copy constructor,into the class,the output became like this:

output:

```
call Test::constructor
call func
call Test::destructor
```

Things became just right now.
Can someone explain this phenomenon to me?Thank u very much.

Comment: You forgot the copy/move constructors.

Comment: If you don't create a copy constructor the compiler will create one on its own.

Answer (score 3):

- Your interpretation of your original code (that the implicitly-declared copy constructor is being called) is correct.

  - Depending on the version of the standard that your compiler is implementing, it may actually be using the implicitly-declared move constructor instead. But this amounts to the same thing.
- Your modified code (where you've explicitly provided a copy constructor) happens to be triggering [the *copy elision* optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), where the compiler just constructs the object in the desired location to begin with. This is one of the few situations where the standard specifically allows an optimization even though it affects the observable behavior of the program (since you can tell whether your copy constructor was called).
- Nothing about your modified code *requires* copy elision, and nothing about your original code *forbids* it; the two versions just happen to differ in whether they trigger the optimization in your compiler under your current settings.

  - Note: the situation here changes a bit in C++17, where this optimization does become mandatory in some cases. See my above link for details.

**Edited to add:** Incidentally, in your version with an explicit copy constructor, your constructor is unusual in taking a *non-constant* reference. This actually means that it can't be used anyway, since a non-constant reference can't bind to the temporary `Test(1)`. I think this oddness may have to do with why your compiler is performing copy elision. If you change the constructor to take a *constant* reference, as the implicitly-declared copy constructor would, you may see the behavior you were expecting, with your explicit copy constructor being called and the destructor being called twice. (But that's just speculation on my part; you'll have to try it and see!)

Comment: Interestingly, the exact same behavior can be observed under g++ (after fixing the copy ctor to take a const reference and renaming `_tmain`.) It seems that the compiler doesn't perform copy elision if the copy ctor is trivial (no side effects, no members with copy ctors, boiling down to a bitwise copy), although it would avoid a destructor call. This is probably a highly unlikely scenario in real code - due to the rule of three/five, an object with a trivial copy constructor would also have a trivial destructor, which is why the compiler doesn't bother optimizing the case when they mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You have two objects of class Test. Since you pass arguments by value, one is constructed explicitly in the main function, another one is constructed with default copy constructor, as your copy constructor is commented out. Both objects get destructed. One on the exit from func(), another at the exit from main(). Hence two destructor calls.